# How Can I Speed Up Android XML Parsing?

Tags: java, android, xml, xml-parsing

Good afternoon (depending on where you live)!

I'm fairly new to Android development and I'm currently working on moving the functionality from an existing iOS app to Android. Part of this functionality is to parse a "large" (~13,000 line) RSS XML file that contains about 500 entries. I've spent anywhere from 10-15 hours researching XML parsing on Android AND trying out the major XML parsers: DOM, SAX, and Pull-parsing. Here are my results, running within' the emulator on my box (32-bit Windows Vista, 2.2 GHz Dual CPU, 3 GB RAM):

SAX: ~6:00 minutes

Pull-Parsing: ~4:00 minutes

DOM: Greater than 4:00 minutes, but didn't time it when I had that implementation coded.

I also tried this RSS Reader from github, but it took >10:00 minutes:

https://github.com/matshofman/Android-RSS-Reader-Library

The implementations for the SAX, PP, and DOM were all taken from stackoverflow.com threads, so I feel fairly confident that I didn't do anything non-standard in them (though, I'm not ruling that out). I've decided to appeal to a larger, more experienced, crowd to get some ideas of what else I can try.

I don't have any control over the format of the file. If I was implementing this end-to-end, I would just write a Web Service that did all the heavy-lifting on the server and then sent down a small, compact, JSON-serialized list. Instead, I have the 13K line file. :)

Any insight into what I can do? It seems to be a fairly common problem, but most responses just say to try one of the different main XML parsers. In my case, I've tried all three and even the fastest seems way too slow.

What am I doing wrong? Are there any normal "newbie" problems that people usually encounter when doing XML parsing over the network on Android???

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide!

Comment: Is it static content?  You could convert it to JSON (there are converters online and a number of text editors that will do the job).  For regular data, JSON is much faster.

Comment: Unfortunately no, it is NOT static - it's changed a couple times a week as more messages are recorded. What you suggest IS interesting, though. Since it changes so infrequently I COULD convert it periodically, but that just adds something else to the mix I have to deal with. Good info and I'll take what you have recommended into consideration.

Comment: to the end to end (wish it was json) bit.  What if you wrote a piggyback server app.  I've done this for my apps when the source content was nuts.  My app hits a service that hits the actual destination.  Loaded it up on heroku (free) and it was all good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [vtd-xml](http://vtd-xml.sourceforge.net/).

[Here are some benchmarks.](http://vtd-xml.sourceforge.net/benchmark1.html)

Also, the emulator is extremely slow, so try it on a real device and you will likely see great improvements.

Comment: The biggest problem, as you eluded to, is that the emulator is VERY SLOW. On my PC, the XML-parsing code takes 7-8 minutes. On an old LG LS670, running Android 2.3.3, it took 6 seconds!

"Great improvements" from using a real device is the understatement of the year. Ha! Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Choosing to run the x86 emulator also speeds things up - significantly. It takes only 17 seconds to pull and load the data. Here's a decent article on installing it: http://www.pommepause.com/blog/2012/09/how-to-run-a-super-fast-android-emulator-with-intel-x86-system-images/ 

I don't have hardware acceleration and it's still WAY faster.

Comment: staggering how slow the emulator is eh.  Considering the PPC, blackberry and even palm had emulators and ran like ten bears were chasing them.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with **Jave's**  answer. The best choice is [VTD-XML library](http://vtd-xml.sourceforge.net/)
This example demonstrate how you can use this library.

XML file:

```
 <database name="products">
        <table name="category">
            <column name="catId">20</column>
            <column name="catName">Fruit</column>
        </table>
        <table name="category">
            <column name="catId">31</column>
            <column name="catName">Vegetables</column>
        </table>
        <table name="category">
            <column name="catId">45</column>
            <column name="catName">Rice</column>
        </table>
        <table name="category">
            <column name="catId">50</column>
            <column name="catName">Potatoes</column>
        </table>
</database>
```

Source code example:

```
import com.ximpleware.AutoPilot;
import com.ximpleware.VTDGen;
import com.ximpleware.VTDNav;


String fileName = "products.xml";

VTDGen vg = new VTDGen();

if (vg.parseFile(fileName, true)) {

     VTDNav vn = vg.getNav();
     AutoPilot table = new AutoPilot(vn);
     table.selectXPath("database/table");

     while (table.iterate()) {
        String tableName = vn.toString(vn.getAttrVal("name"));
        
        if (tableName.equals("category")) {
            AutoPilot column = new AutoPilot(vn);
            column.selectElement("column");

            while (column.iterate()) {
                 String text = vn.toNormalizedString(vn.getText());
                 String name = vn.toString(vn.getAttrVal("name"));
                 
                 if (name.equals("catId")) {
                    Log.d("Category ID = " + text);
                 } else if (name.equals("catName")) {
                    Log.d("Category Name = " + text);
                 } 
                 
            }
        }
     }
}
```

it works for me and hope it helps you.